# I have been playing with Forms, I run a Form with Start-Job with the option to stop it a 2nd job (Robocopy) I also have running

Tags: powershell, winforms, start-job

first, I have been playing with powershell for some time BUT I'm no programmer, so please keep that in mind
There are 2 way my script ends,
1 - I click on the Form's Stop Button All works fine, the Form closed and the second Job (robocopy) gets stopped all Good
2 - the Robocopy job ends then I need to close\stop the Form, the Stop-job\Remove-Job (with the -force option) work BUT there is a very Long delay as it stops the still "Running" Form job that is waiting for a key\button press

can anyone help

a stated the stop-job works but there is a very long delay, I have even been able to get the PID of  the Form job and kill that (taskkill /f /pid) the Form window closes, but the get-job still show the Job state as "running" and Stop-job still have a very Long delay !!

Comment: Does `Remove-Job ... -Force` work? Have you tested [Start-ThreadJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob) instead? Are you using some *Sleep* methods? -- Can you post the code you have?

Comment: yep tried Remove-Job with -Force, the main issue is that the Form is waiting for a the 'enter key' or a mouse click. I have work out a way around this, I issue the Stop-Job command then go on with other stuff giving it time to stop then at the end of the script I do a big cleanup of all the Job's, not the best but it works. What I really need is an easy way tp send a 'enter key' or a mouse click to the background job